# Can camera wires be placed under the roof tiles?

Tags: roof, wire

I am about to have my roof tiles removed temporarily to place new roof paper down. Can the camera wires currently running over the tiles, now be put under them?

Comment: what type of tiles? concrete, asphalt, decrabond are all tiles after a fashion, but completely different.

Comment: What are you going to do if the cameras ever need to be replaced with something that uses different cabling, or if there's an issue with the existing cabling, tear up the whole roof to fix the security system? Probably a bad idea. Plus, as noted above, "tiles" come in many different kinds and you may well end up with and uneven roof if you put something uneven _under_ the roofing material.

Comment: Any crimp forces to coax may affect signal quality. Is it smooth?

Comment: I don’t usually place video coax or Ethernet on roofs the heat can affect both types they are they low voltage? As far as code if mains voltage no.

Answer (score 2):

They shouldn't be running either over or under roof tiles :) They should be running in the space underneath the roof structure, or get rerouted elsewhere.